# How to apply for a job in a different country for a parent company?

Tags: applications, international

I work for company A, which was acquired by company B some years ago. During my day to day job, I work closely with people from company B.

I'm looking to move to another country, where company A has no presence but company B does.

I found a position in the other country for company B. How do I go about applying for this position without company A finding out?

Comment: Why do you wish to prevent Company A finding out? (but assuming there's any kind of shared HR between the two companies, the answer is "you probably can't stop them finding out")

Comment: This question is far too vague as currently written. If A was aquired by B, why should they care if you want to work for B, don't you already? What are the sizes of the companies? 10k employees vs 50 makes a big difference. Anything else you can add would be helpful

Comment: @RobinClower at a guess they're not fully merged yet, or A is being kept as a fully owned subsidiary instead of being fully integrated.

Answer (score 2):

> I found a position in the other country for company B. How do I go
> about applying for this position without company A finding out?

Talk to Company B's HR. Ask that they keep the discussion confidential.

Answer (score 2):

1. Read your employee handbook(s). Most will have a policy for internal transfers.
2. Figure out whether the company can/will sponsor relocation/visa etc. for your target country. If they don't, there is no point in applying.
3. If both 1) and 2) check out, apply using the process defined by the company. This may or may not involve informing your line manager early on.
4. If there is no written process, reach out to the new job's HR/recruiter and ask them how the want to handle this.

They may or may not agree to keep this confidential. Internal transfers often require the sign off of the current manager and the new manager will probably want to talk with your current manager about you and get some references and feedback. In some companies transfers are perfectly acceptable or even encouraged, in other companies it's more difficult.

If they won't keep it confidential, you have to make a decision whether to apply or not.

Answer (score 0):

You work for company B now, ever since A was acquired by B. What you want to do is to apply internal transfer to the division of B in the country you move to.

People in A will know it when you apply because A and B are the same company. HR in B will ask for your personnel file after they receive your application.

There is no way A has no knowledge about your application because your work history is listed in your resume and HR in B will read it and they will check it with A.

Comment: just wondering why this is downvoted... ?

Comment: I guess because it's not very nuanced. HR between the two companies maybe totally integrated in which case it's correct. But also HR between the two companies may still be completely separate and they wouldn't inform your manager until the a job offer is ready (which is what the OP is worried about I think)

Comment: In OP's question, "_During my day to day job, I work closely with people from company B._" Also, in my answer, "_your work history is listed in your resume and HR in B will read it_".